# How to collect multiple callbacks to call once a task is done

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, node.js

I can't seem to find a general solution to this problem, even though I feel like I can't be the first to come across this. I also suspect it might be I'm taking the wrong approach in the first place here. Let me know.

I have an Expressjs App the interacts with various APIs (mostly OAuth2). Once a request comes in the App checks if it has an access token to fetch data from an API. In case the token is expired it will request a new one.

Now, when my App receives a second request in the meantime, requiring the exact same API, I want to avoid making a second call for an access token.

What I do is use a "Collector" where callbacks can be stored for a given key. The first request to store a callback for a key gets a collector callback to invoke once it has finished  the task. All subsequent callbacks are enqueued and called later on with the collector callback.

This is the simple Collector class (CoffeeScript)

```
# Collect callbacks for tasks and execute all once the job is done
module.exports = class Collector
  constructor: ()->
    @tasks = {}
  add: (key, callback)->
    unless @tasks[key]
      # Initiate callback list for the key with first callback
      @tasks[key] = [callback]
      return ()=>
        # Call all collected callbacks for the key
        (callback.apply {}, arguments for callback in @tasks[key])
        # Reset callback list
        @tasks[key] = null
    else
      # Add callback to existing list
      @tasks[key].push callback
      return false
```

I'm not sure if storing the callbacks inside this class is the right way, but to use a database (Redis) I would have to find a way to store callbacks…

Is there a better way to invoke multiple callbacks once a job is done?

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just aggregate your callbacks into an array which you cycle through, executing each contained function when your original call is complete?

It could be as simple as:

```
var dones = [];

dones.push(function (err, res) { console.log('hoo'); });
dones.push(function (err, res) { console.log('ray!'); });

function whenDone(err, res) { 
   _.each(dones, function (done) { done(err, res); } }); 
}

myWhateverFunction(whenDone);
```

You can wrap this into whatever data structure you want, if you want to make it prettier.

Comment: That is exactly what I do right now :) I'm collecting the callbacks like you do in `dones` and I hand the `whenDone` method back to the first one that gives me a callback so he can call it once the job is done (and all collected callbacks are called)

Only difference is a have different `dones`, identified by a given key. And I wrap it in a class.

Comment: To add to that: What I do and what you suggest works perfectly. However, what about once I have to store hundreds of callbacks at any time? Will this still work? Is an array inside that file really the right place to store such data?

Comment: What you're approaching is a pattern called the Saga pattern, typical to distributed event based systems

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a specific answer to your problem, but you should check out the async module. I think it's a step in the right direction: https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for the suggestion. I am aware of the async module and already use it heavily in my app. It does not, however, provide a solution to my problem (e.g. doesn't allow providing additional callbacks once it runs)

Comment: I was worried I missed something. Sorry about that.